# Why is nvim updating the clipboard on start?

Tags: vimrc, neovim, gvim, macos

I use `set clipboard=unnamed` in my configuration. When I open nvim with `nvim`, the clipboard is left unchanged but if I open with `nvim .` the latest entry of the clipboard is always something unexpected.

For example, let's say I do the following:

- using [Alfred](https://www.alfredapp.com/help/features/clipboard/), I run "Clear Clipboard History".
- using the terminal, I run `pbcopy < /dev/null`.
- I add `1`, `2` and `3` to my clipboard history. I can see those entries using Alfred
- I open nvim with `nvim .`

My clipboard history is showing:

```
4
3
2
1
```

`4` isn't expected here. I don't always see a number like `4` but I always get something I don't want as the latest entry. I got the feeling nvim keeps some sort of history somewhere and populates the clipboard on startup.
I run the same experience with `vim` and `gvim` and I get:

- `vim`:

```
../
```

- `gvim` :

```
3
2
1
```

What I see with `gvim` is the behavior I expect. [Here](https://github.com/mathieux51/.cfg/blob/master/.vimrc) is my complete `.vimrc` file.

Comment: `vim .` should open the current directory in netrw (not sure about neovim), so I'm confused what that has to do with the clipboard pieces. Maybe have a look at [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604) and see if you can reproduce this with a smaller vimrc

Comment: Thanks @D.BenKnoble. After you pointed out netrw, I found a solution by removing [tpope/vim-vinegar](https://github.com/tpope/vim-vinegar) plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the plugin [tpope/vim-vinegar](https://github.com/tpope/vim-vinegar) and now everything works as expected. I browsed couple of issues, like [this one](https://github.com/tpope/vim-vinegar/issues/40), and it seems this is a netrw bug.